# Phalcon Validator PresenceOf

Tags: php, phalcon

Если верить [документации](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Validation_Validator_PresenceOf.html), то метод `PresenceОf` должен проверять на null/empty строки.
Вот кусок моего кода:

```
public function validation()
{
    $validator = new Validation();

    $validator->add(['name', 'email'], new PresenceOf([
        'message' => [
           'name'  => 'Вы не указали имя',
           'email' => 'Вы не указали E-mail'
        ]
    ]));

    return $this->validate($validator);
}
```

но в результате все равно стандартные надписи выводит:

> name is required
>
> email is required

Версия 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по исходникам и примерам, нужно делать так:

```
new PresenceOf([
    "field"   => "name",
    "message" => "The name is required",
])
```

а не как у вас

```
new PresenceOf([
    'message' => [
       'name'  => 'Вы не указали имя',
       'email' => 'Вы не указали E-mail'
    ]
])
```

т.е. элемент массива с ключом `message` должен быть строкой.

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.1.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Validator_PresenceOf.html

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/validator/presenceof.zep